# Does the energy of an RBM only depend on the architecture?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning

I am browsing the web for days now, looking for answer for my question, yet I fail to understand this topic well enough to be able to interpret the books I find.

Here's what I understand now:

I think I get supervised learning. You have a data set of (x,y) pairs. You make a model, feed the x's to it, retrieve y's, and then try to minimize some cost function depending on how far your model shoots off.

RBM's are usually used for unsupervised learning, as in you only have (x) values. Therefore, you can not create a cost function to minimize. Instead, you define an energy function, which depends on the activations of the neurons and the weights in between them. When you got the minimal energy, you trained the model.

But this last thought tells me that the energy, therefore the optimized structure of the model depends only on the architecture, and is independent of the input data. So only by setting the number of input and hidden neurons, you pre-define the weights and biases of the net.

So is it really so? Does the training of an RBM happen independently of the dataset we want to apply it on?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the point of unsupervised learning.

> RBM's are usually used for unsupervised learning, as in you only have (x) values. Therefore, you can not create a cost function to minimize.

This is simply false, you can define many valid cost functions, they simply do not depend on the label (as there is no label). But consider for example kmeans model, where you position K points in the input space, your cost here is a sum of distances of your Xs to the closes point from these K.

> Instead, you define an energy function, which depends on the activations of the neurons and the weights inbetween them. When you got the minimal energy, you trained the model.

Energy-based reasoning is just one of many possibilities. In particular, this makes sense for RBM.

> But this last thought tells me that the energy, therefore the optimized structure of the modell depends only on the architecture, and is independent of the input data.

This is false, as **activation** is **a function of data**. You do not have network activation without a data being processed. Accodring to such reasoning, supervised learning would also be "independent of the input data" because what your network produces for a given x is **also an activation** (of the output layer).

> So only by setting the number of input and hidden neurons, you pre-define the weights and biases of the net.

No, this makes no sense at all. At most it defines number of parameters in RBM, not actual values.

> So is it really so? Does the training of an RBM happen independently of the dataet we want to apply it on?

As a consequence of the above answers - no. RBM training modifies weights in order to minimize energy, which is defined as a function of weights **and activations** (which, on the other hand, are **data dependant elements**).

Comment: Alright, I see my error here. Thank you for pointing this out to me.